# how to avoid my sent email not be classified as spam?

Tags: email, spam

I am operating a website that can send invitation to other people, I encountered a problem that the emails sent from my website are all classified as spam in the major email sevice providers, I am just wondering how I can avoid this as much as possible.

Basically what I am doing now:

1) User input friend's email

2) I use python to send the email, the email is simple - pure text, just a line of words to tell people that your friend is inviting you, and the website has created an account for him, the password is **

3) The 'from' of the email is the user who is sending the invitation(I am wondering if this contribute to the spamness?), not my website's email.

Thanks.
Bin

Comment: Regarding question 3, the more correct way would be that the email comes from your website (the from), and the user sending the invitation email address would be in the reply-to.  I don't know if this helps make it look less like spam, though.

Comment: A proper answer to your question would take the better part of a book. Fortunately, Jeff Atwood, one of this site's founders, has already given the matter a fairly concise treatment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your third point is a major reason you get marked as spam. You are sending emails with addresses from another domain then the domain of your server, and you change which email this is all the time. This is a typical spammers behavior.

Answer (score 5):

1. [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam) will give you some useful tips.
2. [Ways to prevent email being blocked as Spam](http://www.allspammedup.com/2009/09/7-ways-to-prevent-your-emails-being-blocked-as-spam/)